# How to invoke an exe in path by the (cmd) Process object?

Tags: .net, cmd

```
            var cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        cmd.Start();



        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(Input.Text);
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        Output.Text += cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Output.Text += "\n";
```

When invoking .exe's from path, there is no standard output displayed.

**EDIT: Seems the output went into standard error, which gave me the perception, that the .exe's were'nt actually called. Solved**

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. `PATH` is set when `cmd.exe` loads, and the existing `PATH` is available to it at that point. Your final line just tries to set `PATH` equal to what `PATH` already is, which of course is meaningless - it's like saying `i = 1; i = i;` in two successive lines of code. Can you edit to clarify exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish (the reason you're trying to set the `PATH`)?

Comment: @KenWhite Path does indeed get set during cmd load. Oddly enough, i'm still unable to invoke the commands from the path. I'm trying to accomplish the possibility of invoking the commands from the path like you normally would from the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Try that before you start the process:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", pathValue);
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx

but when you do that i think you should concat the current value of the path environment value